# android refrofit kotlin fetching json from api do nothing

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have **REST API** like bottom and also **kotlin** app but i cant get data from it and also do nothing.

I used **JSON** can be reason is that? I tried most of things but nothing.

when i remove name `flyList`
i can get it but i dont have to remove that name.

pls help.

JSON:

```
{
   "flyList":[
      {
         "pgt_id":1198952,
         "dmlsts":"U",
         "newparkpos":"1",
         "preparkpos":"3",
         "rkgelcag":"PGT82N",
         "rkgelpltar":"2021-07-31 00:00:00.0",
         "rkgelplsaat":"16:55:00",
         "rkgidcag":"PGT2260",
         "rkgidpltar":"2021-07-31 00:00:00.0",
         "rkgidplsaat":"18:00:00",
         "send":1,
         "delFly":0
      },
      {
         "pgt_id":1198826,
         "dmlsts":"U",
         "newparkpos":"204B",
         "preparkpos":"201A",
         "rkgelcag":"PGT14J",
         "rkgelpltar":"2021-07-31 00:00:00.0",
         "rkgelplsaat":"14:30:00",
         "rkgidcag":"PGT59K",
         "rkgidpltar":"2021-07-31 00:00:00.0",
         "rkgidplsaat":"17:35:00",
         "send":1,
         "delFly":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Code:

```
private fun loadData(){
         val retrofit=Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .build()

         val  service =retrofit.create(FlightAPI::class.java)

         val call=service.getData()

         call.enqueue(object : Callback<FlightModel> {
             override fun onResponse(call: Call<FlightModel>, response: Response<FlightModel>) {

                 if (response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                     var data=response.body();
                 }
             }

             override fun onFailure(call: Call<FlightModel>, t: Throwable) {
                 TODO("Not yet implemented")
             }


         })


    }
    }
```

I separated data class **Flight List** and flight......

```
data class FlightModel(
    val flyList: List<Fly>
)


data class Fly(
    val delFly: Int,
    val dmlsts: String,
    val newparkpos: String,
    val pgt_id: Int,
    val preparkpos: Any,
    val rkgelcag: String,
    val rkgelplsaat: String,
    val rkgelpltar: String,
    val rkgidcag: String,
    val rkgidplsaat: String,
    val rkgidpltar: String,
    val send: Int
)
```

Answer (score 0):

api inetrface like that

interface FlightAPI {

```
     fun getData():Call<FlightModel>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem  t did like that

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<FlightModel>{
             override fun onResponse(call: Call<FlightModel>, response: Response<FlightModel>) {
                var  flightModel =response?.body()
                flightModels = flightModel?.flyList as ArrayList<Fly>?

                 for (fly : Fly in flightModels!!){
                     println("Gel_Ad.........:"+fly.rkgelcag)
                 }


             }
```